# Chartfx new chart object not initialized?

Tags: webforms, chartfx

When I create a new chart object via:

```
ChartFX.WebForms.Chart theChart = new ChartFX.WebForms.Chart();
```

When I took a look immediately the row after creation via breakpoint in Visual Studio 2005 I noticed there are 3 rows in the newly created chart that have data.  Is this a bug? or do I need to call a specific function?  Shouldn't the data table for the chart be initialized to all 0's on creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ChartFX this is by design.  After the declaration of the chart object you can clear it out using:

```
chart1.Data.Clear();
```